# How to preselect an item using Javascript when the page renders

Tags: listbox, listboxitem

I have a drupal rendered webform that generates the following HTML for a SELECT list. The list is essentially for booking a table in a restaurant. My client wants me to preselect the meal based on the time of the day. So if its between midnight and 3:00 pm Lunch should be preselected automatically. After 3:00 pm till 10:30pm the form should display with dinner preselected.

```
<select class="form-select required" name="submitted[meal]" id="edit-submitted-meal">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Lunch</option>
  <option value="2">Dinner</option>
  <option value="3">Sunday Dining</option>
</select>
```

I created the following JS snippet hoping to achieve the objective but it doesn't seem to work on Page load

```
window.onload() {
  var today = new Date("<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>");
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var meallist = document.getElementbyId("#edit-submitted-meal");
  if  (day == 0) {
    meallist.options[3].selected==true;
  }
  else {  
    if (hour > 15 && hour < 22) {
      meallist.options[2].selected==true;
    }
    else if (hour > 22 && hour < 24 {
      meallist.options[1].selected==true;
    }
    else if (hour > 0 && hour < 15 {
      meallist.options[1].selected==true;
    }
  }
}
```

Would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

PS : The PHP code injects the date into the javascript so when the page is rendered the line becomes var today = new Date("2013-01-15 15:49:45");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your javascript syntax

```
   window.onload(){
      //your code here
   }
```

should be

```
   window.onload = (function(){ 
      //your code here
    });
```

Also when using document.getElementById you don't want to include the '#'

and for setting a variable as in

```
 meallist.options[1].selected==true;
```

you only want to use a single =

```
  meallist.options[1].selected=true;
```

Also bear in mind that the options array is 0 based. E.g options value=3 is actually

```
  meallist.options[2] not [3]
```

A simplified version can be found here
http://jsfiddle.net/N7Yhr/

Do you have any other errors in your console window (firebug etc)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I fixed a couple of other bugs. If you notice there are no closing braces for the else if conditions. Also the variable date should be today instead. Having done that I still have one error being reported by firebug TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function
http://potlim.sastratechnologies.biz/potlibookonline
Line 122

Comment: I fixed the error I mentioned above, the "b" was not capitalised - document.getElementbyId should actually be document.getElementById. Now I have no errors but on page load it doesn't display "dinner" if the current time is after 3pm

Comment: I guess the issue is in fetching the day and hour on the third and fourth lines.

Comment: I guess the issue is in converting the server date that is injected by PHP on the third and fourth lines. Let me figure out a way to do this. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR TIME. YOU HAVE BEEN MOST HELPFUL. By the way this is my second JavaScript program. I mostly work on PHP.